# How to start emulation between two nfc devices in android

Tags: android, nfc

I have to share tag from one device to other, i have android 2.3.3 galaxy.
please share me some code for sharing tag from one device to another.

I have taken this code from developer site but it shows error in that line

```
 mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);


  // Check for available NFC Adapter
 mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
 if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
     Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     finish();
     return;
 }
 // Register callback
 mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);
```

now i m using  enable forground message but it works fine but how to see emulation ..

```
public class DemoNFCtagActivity extends Activity {

    NdefMessage msg;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

           mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundNdefPush(this,msg );

    }

    NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
    TextView textView;

    Button btnEmulation;
    PendingIntent mNfcPendingIntent;
    IntentFilter[] mNdefExchangeFilters;
    NdefMessage message;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       // TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        // Check for available NFC Adapter
        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        // Register callback
    //    mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);


        String text = ("Beam me up, Android!\n\n" +
                "Beam Time: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
         msg = new NdefMessage(
                new NdefRecord[] { createMimeRecord(
                        "application/com.example.android.beam", text.getBytes())
         /**
          * The Android Application Record (AAR) is commented out. When a device
          * receives a push with an AAR in it, the application specified in the AAR
          * is guaranteed to run. The AAR overrides the tag dispatch system.
          * You can add it back in to guarantee that this
          * activity starts when receiving a beamed message. For now, this code
          * uses the tag dispatch system.
          */
          //,NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.example.android.beam")
        });     
    }

    public NdefRecord createMimeRecord(String mimeType, byte[] payload) {
        byte[] mimeBytes = mimeType.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
        NdefRecord mimeRecord = new NdefRecord(
                NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA, mimeBytes, new byte[0], payload);
        return mimeRecord;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback()` is only available in Android 4.0 ICS and later. Use `enableForegroundNdefPush()` instead.

Comment: i have one another problem ,i am using code describe above..
but how to see emulation means that code not showing any error ,but nothing happend..please help